# how to get last 10 added records in sqlite table in iphone

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite

I have table view in which I want to select last 10 records added in query. I am using following query which return all the records but I want last 10 added.

here is the query

> NSString* select = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * FROM
>   ContentMaster  where ContentAddedByUserID='%@' AND
>   HiveletCode='%@'",appDelegate.userID,appDelegate.organizationCode];

I have searched some where that we can get by top records like this I get that we can fetch using date between two dates any idea how to get without date last 10 records.

I want to fetch all data which is last 10 added.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every row in a table has an [unique ID](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), which you can use for your query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ContentMaster
WHERE
    ContentAddedByUserID='%@'
AND
    HiveletCode='%@'
ORDER BY
    rowid DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), each row in the Sqlite contains a 64 Bit auto incremented id associated with it.
So you can use query as

```
SELECT * FROM ContentMaster WHERE ContentAddedByUserID='%@' AND HiveletCode='%@'
ORDER BY ROWID DESC
LIMIT 10
```

**Remember,**

1. If you declare an ordinary table column to use one of the defined special names `ROWID, _ROWID_, or OID`, then the use of that name will refer to the declared column not to the internal `ROWID`.
2. If a table contains a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then that column becomes an alias for the `ROWID`.